# VMWare guest OS as bridge gives BSOD in host (bridge.sys)

Tags: windows-8, vmware, hyper-v

I'm using Windows 8 x64 with a Ubuntu 12.04 x64 guest in VMWare. I'm trying to use the guest network as bridged but it always gives me a BSOD:

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (bridge.sys)

I already disabled Hyper-V on Windows 8 (programs and features) and installed VMWare tools in guest OS. What else do I need to do?